# React-native and it dont work, accusing some error "Task 'installRelease' not found in project ':app'"

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I have this problem and did a lot of research but none of answer worked for me.
SO: Windows 10
Android Studio version: latest version
React-native version: 4.6.3

ERROR: 
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: try Android Studio > Build > Clean Project

Comment: thanks for comminting @MayconMesquita, i tried before and didnt work, i solved the problem tho.

Comment: So, great job!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, i solved it, im postting this to help someone in the future.
To solve it I used Android Studio to Open the folder **android** on the project and it install all missing dependecies and files.